# How to add a custom field created with acf for user account to be displayed in checkout form in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I had created a custom field with ACF in the user account that displays a message about payment method. I can't make it display in the checkout page.

I've added this code to checkout-form.php but is not working, it displays only "empty". "payment_method_message" is the field name in ACF.

```
<?php $value = get_field( "payment_method_message", $user );

echo $value;

?>
```

What I want is to display this field before the finish order button. Thank you in advance!

Note:
Also I tried to add this in function.php but nothing again...

```
    add_action('woocommerce_after_order_note','display_acf_field_on_checkout'); 

    function display_acf_field_on_checkout()
    
    { echo '<b>Payment method message:</b>' . 
    get_field('payment_method_message',$user_id); 
    // Note: 'payment_method_message' is the slug of the ACF }
```

SOLVED: I figured it out with the below code, which I put it in payment.php template in childtheme woocommerce directory. It works well.

```
<?php 

$value = get_field('payment_method_message',  
'user_'.get_current_user_id());

if( $value = get_field( 'payment_method_message',  
'user_'.get_current_user_id() ) ) { echo "<h3 style='margin:0;font- 
weight: 600;'>" . 'Payment Method: '  .  $value . '</h3>' ; }

?>
```

Comment: How you define `$user` variable? I think the problem comes from there… You should try to use `if( $value = get_field( "payment_method_message", get_current_user_id() ) ) { echo value; }`

Comment: I made this change but still nothing... I'm at very beginnig to this so I can't figure what I'm doing wrong....                                                                          
       <?php 
 $value = get_field('payment_method_message', $user);
 $user= get_current_user_id() ;
 if( $value = get_field( "payment_method_message", get_current_user_id() ) ) { 
    echo value; 
    ?>

Comment: Also i tryied to add this in function.php but nothing again...`add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_note', 'display_acf_field_on_checkout');
 
function display_acf_field_on_checkout() {
  echo '<b>Payment method message:</b> ' . get_field('payment_method_message',$user_id);
  // Note: 'payment_method_message' is the slug of the ACF
}`

Comment: ACF is capricious on some cases and depend on your settings… So I can't give you anything else.